# How to include multiple directories in arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino

I have my arduino libraries folder which holds one library called DHT_sensor_Library. In this folder, I have another folder called DHT_U. In this folder, I have DHT_U.ccp and DHT_U.h.

The problem is that when I include DHT_U.h in my arduino IDE:

```
#include "DHT_U.h"
```

The error says:
    Tempreture_Humidity_Sensor:2:19: error: DHT_U.h: No such file or directory

```
compilation terminated.

exit status 1
DHT_U.h: No such file or directory
```

I have already tried
`#include "DHT_U/DHT_U.h"`  ,
`#include "DHT_U\DHT_U.h"`
and 
`#include ..\DHT_U.h"`. None of these worked.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
#include "DHT.h"
#include "DHT_U.h"
#include "LiquidCrystal.h"
#include "DHT.h"
```

Full code can be shown here:

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>

// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include "DHT.h"

// set the DHT Pin
#define DHTPIN 8

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  dht.begin();

  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("Temp:  Humidity:");
}

void loop() {
  delay(500);
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // read humidity
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  //read temperature in Fahrenheit
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

  if (isnan(h) || isnan(f)) {
    lcd.print("ERROR");
    return;
  }

  lcd.print(f);
  lcd.setCursor(7,1);
  lcd.print(h);  
}
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Hi, @SreeniH, two questions for you. Are you on Win10 operational system? Did you add this library through the library manager on Arduino IDE?

Comment: I am on Win10 operating system. I added this through the library manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the hole path like `"/home/your_username/arduino/lib/foo.h"` or something like this. Are you sure it is a `.h` file and not a `.hpp` ?

Comment: it is a h file.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that you need to be careful when your `#include` methods.

If `DHT_U.h` is located in the same direction as your `.ino` file you can include it with this:

```
#include "DHT_U.h"
```

However, if you installed the library using the library manager from Arduino IDE, you should do:

```
#include <DHT_U.h>
```

If none of these works, make sure that you have installed correctly your library. You could try by testing the examples from the Arduino IDE with the library that you have installed.